# I want to save all GET data in SESSION, how do I do it?

Tags: php, html, get, session-variables

I have 15 GET variables.

```
$_GET['data1'];
$_GET['data2'];
$_GET['data3'];
$_GET['data4'];
```

I there a way to store these in session without doing it-*the code below* 15 times?

```
$_SESSION['data1'] = $_GET['data1'];
```

Help, Thank you

Comment: Please have a look at the basic tutorial about loops on the php website: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: thanks. but I figured out way to do it without using loops.

Comment: How did you do it? Certainly, using loops is most likely the best solution here and if you're learning to program, understanding loops is very important as you'll need it very often.

Comment: yeah, I'm starting to learn how to use loops now, thanks to you. I posted my answer below if you want to take a look. Thank you bro.

Comment: What you've done also works, although it's something different than your original question. Just watch out doing that, because if $_GET contains other data you don't want to store, you're also storing that in the session. It's easy to abuse it that way.

Comment: ah. I see. thanks. I may have to modify my html and php for it to be secure. I'll be sure to update later if found out something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers. But after some test, I found out the best solution for me.

```
$_SESSION['data'] = $_GET;
```

Saves all the get data as array in $_SESSION['data']

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work

```
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
    {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I think this is the most decent way to solve this using for loops. but I have also found a way to solve it without using loops.